# Upgrading from v2.3.0 to 2.3.4

Tags: magento2, upgrade, composer, setup-upgrade

I need to upgrade a Magento instance from v2.3.0 to v2.3.5 later this month.

I'm wondering if I need to upgrade to v2.3.1 and run `setup:upgrade` first,
and then repeat for v2.3.2, v2.3.3, v2.3.4 before upgrading to v2.3.5?

Or can I upgrade directly from v2.3.0 to v2.3.5?

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.3.5 --update-with-all-dependencies
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need not to update all the Magento version from 2.3.0 to 2.3.4.

You can directly upgrade your Magento store version to 2.3.4 or 2.3.5 (if available) with the below commands.

```
php bin/magento maintenance:enable

composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.3.4 --no-update //for upgrading to Magento 2.3.4

composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.3.5-p1 --no-update //for upgrading Magento version to 2.3.5 patch 1

composer update
```

Remove the data placed under `var`, `pub/static` and `generated` folder with below command.

```
rm -rf var/* pub/static/* generated/*
```

After that, run the below commands.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento indexer:reindex

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento cache:flush
```

After upgrade, check your Magento version and disable the maintenance mode with the below commands.

```
php bin/magento --version

php bin/magento maintenance:disable
```

Hope it helps!!!